# can't generate table for entity OryzoneMediaStorageBundle symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

this my entity class

```
<?php

namespace Application\MainAppBundleBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Oryzone\Bundle\MediaStorageBundle\Entity\Media as BaseMedia;
/**

    Application\MainAppBundleBundle\Entity\Media *
    @ORM\Table(name="media")
    @ORM\Entity() */

class Media extends BaseMedia
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */

protected $id;

 /**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

}
?>
```

when i execute "php app/console doctrine:update:schema --force" i get this message
nothing to update ...
help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hourss2040

I think you can't combine **.orm.yml** and **annotations** in same *Entity*.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved ✔
the problem: when I execute doctrine:schema:update, the update of the data base is based on the files in @ MyBundle / Resources / config / doctrine / MyFiles.orm.yml since I created my entity Entity / media.php and I have not Media.orm.yml the media table will not be created, so I deleted all files * orm.yml and I execute php app / console doctrine.: schema: update and the table is created

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch auto mapping on like this:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
```

Or register your bundle mapping like this:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
       entity_managers:
            default:
                connection:       default
                mappings:
                    MainAppBundleBundle: ~
```

Comment: same problem , look at this class 

namespace Oryzone\Bundle\MediaStorageBundle\Entity;

use Oryzone\MediaStorage\Model\Media as BaseMedia;

abstract class Media extends BaseMedia
{

}